# How can I know who call System.gc() in spark streaming program?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, spark-streaming

The GC time is too long in my spark streaming programme. In the GC log, I found that **Someone called `System.gc()` in the programme**. I do not call `System.gc()` in my code. So the caller should be the api I used.

I add `-XX:-DisableExplicitGC` to JVM and fix this problem. However, I want to know who call the `System.gc()`.

I tried some methods.

1. Use `jstack`. But the GC is not so frequent, it is difficult to dump the thread that call the method.
2. I add trigger that add thread dump when invoke method `java.lang.System.gc()` in JProfiler. But it doesn't seem to work.

How can I know who call System.gc() in spark streaming program?

Comment: Run it in a debugger with a breakpoint?

Comment: @PiRocks , the programme is running on the remote host and the breakpoint does not seem to work in the spark streaming programme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will not catch `System.gc` with `jstack`, because during stop-the-world pauses JVM does not accept connections from Dynamic Attach tools, including `jstack`, `jmap`, `jcmd` and similar.

It's possible to trace `System.gc` callers with [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/):

1. Start profiling beforehand:

   ```
   $ profiler.sh start -e java.lang.System.gc <pid>
   ```
2. After one or more `System.gc` happens, stop profiling and print the stack traces:

   ```
   $ profiler.sh stop -o traces <pid>
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   --- Execution profile ---
   Total samples       : 6

   Frame buffer usage  : 0.0007%

   --- 4 calls (66.67%), 4 samples
     [ 0] java.lang.System.gc
     [ 1] java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory
     [ 2] java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>
     [ 3] java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect
     [ 4] Allocate.main

   --- 2 calls (33.33%), 2 samples
     [ 0] java.lang.System.gc
     [ 1] sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run
   ```

   In the above example, `System.gc` is called 6 times from two places. Both are typical situations when JDK internally forces Garbage Collection.

   The first one is from `java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory`. When there is not enough free memory to allocate a new direct ByteBuffer (because of `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` limit), JDK forces full GC to reclaim unreachable direct ByteBuffers.

   The second one is from GC Daemon thread. This is called periodically by Java RMI runtime. For example, if you use JMX remote, periodic GC is automatically enabled once per hour. This can be tuned with [`-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) system property.